# Ruby Shoes: how to replace button text with an image/icon

Tags: ruby, image, button, shoes

I am trying to write a small Shoes app which contains a button. For example

```
Shoes.app :title => "Buttons" do 
  button_next = button "Next"
  button_prev = button "Previous"
end
```

Now, instead of the texts "Next" or "Previous" there should be icons on the buttons: a green arrow, showing to the right for the button_next and a green arrow showing to the left for the button_prev.

Of couse I already have the icons as .jpg-files but I can't figure out how to replace the text with the icons on the buttons.

For now I found out this way:

```
Shoes.app do 
  next_image = image "next.jpg", :width => 50, :height => 35
  next_image.click do 
    alert "Hey!"
  end
end
```

It works in the way that I can click the image and a new window, saying "Hey!" appears. But it is not ok, because I miss the typical button-appearance like changing of the color when hovering over it, or the press-down-effect when clicking on it.

So my question is: how can I create a real button in Ruby Shoes and replace the name of the button with an icon? Any ideas?

Comment: Use Css hover & button press down effect.

Comment: I don't use Ruby on Rails and I don't create a web application. So I can't apply css here, right?

Comment: No. You can go through the examples mentioned [here](http://shoesrb.com/walkthrough/).

Comment: thx, but I already have worked my way through this tutorial and through the manual, but there are no examples describing how to replace button text with an image. Any concrete ideas?

Comment: Basically, my indended button needs to look like the "OK" button pictured here: http://shoesrb.com/manual/Hello.html. I would just remove the "OK" and leave just the arrow-icon but I have no idea how to place that icon on the button. I would appreciate any hint, since I am trying to find a solution for weeks now.

Comment: Shoes doesn't have that yet. What you are asking is possible though you have to write the behavior yourself. [Mouse events](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Events.html#hover{|self|...}) are supported.